# Google Maps Embed call failing for queries with number signs / pound signs / hash tags

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

My application throws the error:

> Google Maps Platform rejected your request. You must use an API key to
>   authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional
>   information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

I've tried reproducing the bug with a variety of query strings. It appears that the only time that the query fails is when there's a # for a suite number or apartment number.

This works:
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=17426%20Northwest%20Fwy,%20Jersey%20Village,%20TX%2077040,%20USA&key=

This does not work:
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=951%20Interstate%20Hwy%2030%20#105,%20Rockwall,%20TX%2075087,%20USA&key=

A potential solution is that I omit the # tags and just use the Place IDs when I get the initial address.

That requires a huge code refactor, so I would really love not to.

Comment: URL encode the address

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/url-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "#" reserved character is usually used as an anchor for linking subsections and is one of those special characters that should be encoded in URLs.

Try this: https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=951%20Interstate%20Hwy%2030%20%23105,%20Rockwall,%20TX%2075087,%20USA&key=

Refer to Google's documentation on [URL encoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/url-encoding) for more details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm late to say this, but thank you so much! Your answer helped tremendously.

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help! :)